# How to calculate holes with 3 parameters dependent on each other with JS

Tags: javascript, calculation

I need to create simple program who calculate user input data. User need to chose 3  parameters - size, pressure, and units. Size and pressure are from html **select option** and units are from **input**. I can't figure out how to start my calculation code...

**Example:**

size = 100, pressure = 6, units = 10 /// size 100 in pressure 6 have 8 holes with size M8, so the result is 8*10 = 80 holes M8.

size = 100, pressure = 10, units = 10 /// size 100 in pressure 10 have 10 holes with size M8, so the result is 10*10 = 100 holes M8.

size 150, pressure = 10, units = 10 /// size 150 in pressure 10 have 12 holes, with size M10, so the result is 10*10 = 100 holes M10.

end etc.

Size of holes depends of input size.

How many holes depends of pressure.

I need guidance how to start my calculation code. I tried with loops and switch case, but is a lot of code to list sizes from 50 1000, pressure from 4 to 20.

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: **_I tried with loops and switch case, but is a lot of code to list sizes from 50 1000, pressure from 4 to 20._** : So where is it? Please share so you can recieve _guidance_.

Comment: I think the main part of this calculation will be how to get the number of holes, once you have that, then you can do the second part really easily - but as you haven't shown any information about how the number of holes are calculated, then there is not much we  can do

Comment: This is the code for 3 sizes (i need 15+) - https://github.com/kuncavia/JavaScript/blob/master/Flanges/switch.js It's not problem for me to do switch case for all sizes, but in size 80, 100, 150, 200, 250, have different size of holes. So I can calculate numbers of holes, but cant't print numbers and their sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of creating one object like properties and use it with function for calculations based on parameters

1. Create object with size, pressure and corresponding multiplier
2. Create function with parameters - size,  pressure, units
3. Return calculated value based on parameters passed to function with values from properties object
4. Flexible to add new sizes as new object to properties object instead of creating new switch case or updating switch case

```js
var properties = {
50: {
   '6': {multiplier: 4},
  '10': {multiplier: 6},
  '16': {multiplier: 10},
  'na': {multiplier: 12}
 },
80: {
   '6': {multiplier: 6},
  '10': {multiplier: 8},
  '16': {multiplier: 20},
  'na': {multiplier: 24}
 },
100: {
   '6': {multiplier: 8},
  '10': {multiplier: 10},
  '16': {multiplier: 20},
  'na': {multiplier: 24}
 },
150: {
   '6': {multiplier: 8},
  '10': {multiplier: 10},
  '16': {multiplier: 16},
  'na': {multiplier: 26}
 }
}

function calculate(size, pressure, units){
   return properties[size][pressure] ? properties[size][pressure].multiplier* units : properties[size]['na'].multiplier * units ;
}

console.log("size = 100, pressure = 6, units = 10, caculated holes --> ", calculate(100, 6, 10)); // 80
console.log("size = 100, pressure = 10, units = 10, caculated holes --> ", calculate(100, 10, 10)); //100
console.log("size = 150, pressure = 10, units = 10, caculated holes --> ", calculate(150, 10, 10)); // 100
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/VVozqw?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks for answer, it's really easy and simple. I'll try it for all sizes.

Comment: I change little the code: https://pastebin.com/94qt7HKX But how to log boltSize like a string, because in this case I have ReferenceError: boltSize is not defined

Comment: @НиколайМатев, it should be properties[size][pressure].boltSize